# Не находит OPENGL.dll

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

Не находил библиотеки `glut.h`, скачал, кинул `glut.dll`,
`glut32.dll` в `/system32. glut.h` в `/gl. glut.lib`,
`glut32.lib` в `/PlatformSDK/Lib`. И теперь простой пример, компилируется, но на стадии выполнения пишет, что не находит `OPENGL.dll`, где его взять? Спасибо.

Проект делаю в vс++ 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dll'ки должны находится либо в C:\WINDOWS\system32 либо в папке с твоим exe-файлом

Comment: да, они в system32, опечатался(

Comment: там должна быть opengl32.dll, а не OPENGL.dll

Comment: в том-то и дело, opengl32.lib, я подключил и с ней по ходе проблем нет. Пишет, что нет OPENGL.dll. Может я не оттуда скачал glut, есть можешь, дай ссылку, спс.

Comment: я скачивал 3.6 версию.

Comment: http://files.mail.ru/705E12326612415A9ADE9A418A7A173D

Comment: чувак, спасибо, не знаю что произошло, но заработало)

Comment: ну у меня проблем с ними нет ищи где нибудь наверняка старую библиотеку положил

Answer (score 1):

У меня заработало когда я подключил только glut32.dll

"Компоновщик/Ввод/Дополнительные зависимости : glut32.lib"

То есть я убрал glu.dll glut.dll opengl32.dll